# error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int []'

Tags: c++, casting

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class amin
{
private:
    const int length = 10;
    int newArray[length];
    int i;

public:
    int deleteEvenNumber(int getArray[length])
    {

        for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        {
            if (getArray[i] % 2 == 0)
                newArray[i] = getArray[i];
                i++;

        };

        return newArray[length];
    };
};
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    amin manipulateArrays;

    int input , i = 0;
    const int length = 10;
    int mainArray[length];


    cout<<"Please enter ten numbers :"<<endl;

    for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        cin>>input;
        mainArray[i] = input;
        i++;
    };

    manipulateArrays.deleteEvenNumber(mainArray[length]);
};
```

i got these two errors:

1. error C2664: 'amin::deleteEvenNumber' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int []'
2. IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

please help and explain about my mistake to me.

and please introduce a good tutorial for this problem or this title to me.

Comment: I would use a `std::vector` rather than arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `deleteEvenNumber()` requires an `int []` (i.e. `int` array), however you passed it an `int` to it.

```
manipulateArrays.deleteEvenNumber(mainArray[length]);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                         |
                            this is an 'int', not an 'int []'
```

---

To also pass the `length` to the function, you may want to change your function to

```
int deleteEvenNumber(int getArray[], int length)
```

And then call it like:

```
manipulateArrays.deleteEvenNumber(mainArray, length);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `vector<int> mainArray` instead, and then you can easily get its length by `mainArray.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

your function takes an `int[]`(array) as a parameter

```
int deleteEvenNumber(int getArray[length])
```

but you're passing an `int`

```
manipulateArrays.deleteEvenNumber(mainArray[length]);
```