# debugging Overflow problem problem in code

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a hangman program and I'm running into an overflow problem. Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing this? I have tried changing numbers here and there but can't seem to find the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <varargs.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char ch;

    fstream file;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "game file guesses";
        return 1;
    }
    file.open(argv[1],
        ios::in);
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << endl
            << "game: error opening file '"
            << argv[1] << "'"
            << endl << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    int word_count = 0;
    char word[11];
    bool in_word = false;
    int element = 0;
    string str[100];

    while ((ch = file.get()) != EOF)
    {

        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')
        {

            word[element] = ch;
            element++;
            if (!in_word)
            {
                in_word = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            in_word = false;
            word[element] = '\0';
            str[word_count] = string(word);
            word_count++;
            element = 0;
        }
    }
    int x = atoi(argv[2]);
    cout << x << endl;

    file.close();
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int count = (rand() % word_count + 1);
    string random_word = str[count];
    cout << random_word << endl;
    string mask = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < random_word.length(); i++)
    {
        mask = mask + "*";
    }
    cout << mask << endl;


    for (int guesses = 0; guesses < x; )
    {
        cout << "Guess a letter: ";
        string guess;
        cin >> guess;
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k <= random_word.length(); k++)
        {
            if (guess == random_word.substr(k))
```

I think the problem stems from here but I'm not too sure what to try-. Here I'm trying to replace the letters from the guessed letter with the random word

```
{
                    mask.replace(k, 1, 1, guess);
                    cout << mask << endl;
                    cout << "Correct" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
    
                    guesses++;
                }
    
            }
    
        }
        return 0;
    };
```

Comment: Please add the actual error you're seeing to your post, and try to reduce your code to the minimal amount that still reproduces the error.

Comment: The error code is c2664 on the line containing  mask.replace(k, 1, 1, guess);

Comment: Oh, that's a compiler error so it's not an overflow bug. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150353/error-c2664-cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-int-to-int

Comment: I've read the thread but I don't understand how to implement the INT[]

Comment: Specifically I think you're trying to use a version of std::string::replace that doesn't exist. `mask.replace(k, 1, 1, guess[0])` would probably compile. There's no version of `replace` that takes the arguments you're attempting to pass. See https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Using `time(NULL)` as a random number will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.